# Is Azure SQL secure when using it for a desktop program?

Tags: wpf, azure-sql-database

I am working on a WPF database program that will store patient data so needs to be secure. The program will be deployed to remote locations were there is no IT support. I have been asked to store the data in the cloud so it can be backed up as we can't rely on the remote sites to back up the data and we can use report on the data.

My concern is I need to open the SQL ports on the Azure firewall to access the database, none of the end users are on a corporate network they all connect to the web using an ISP.

My question is should I be using SQL Azure like this?

Thanks
Steven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't sound like a good design. I would use some kind of service layer in the cloud which your app connects to. This of course requires you to be always connected, you may as well do a web app then.

But if you just want to backup a local database to the cloud they have a service for that http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/backup/